# How to update two subplots in a loop in ipython notebook within one cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I  have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
#
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2) 
plt.close('all')
for i in range (0,3):
    y  = y + np.pi/2
    f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 4))
    ax1.plot(x, y)     
    ax1.set_title('Title: i=%s' % (i))
    ax1.set_xlabel('X_plot1 title')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Y_plot1 title')    
    ax1.set_xlim ([0.0, 5])
    ax1.set_ylim ([0.0, 6])
    ax2.scatter(x, y)    
    ax2.set_xlabel('Y_plot2 title') 
    ax2.set_ylabel('X_plot2 title')
    plt.show()
```

I would like to show all 3 line plots in subplot 1 and all 3 scatter plots in subplot2.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

[image: plot]

If you don't want to create more than one plot figure, you have to pull the `plt.subplots(...)` call out of the scope of the for loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2) 

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 4))
for i in range (0,3):
    y  = y + np.pi/2    
    ax1.plot(x, y, label="i=%s" % i)     
    #ax1.set_title('Title: i=%s' % (i))
    ax1.set_xlabel('X_plot1 title')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Y_plot1 title')    
    ax1.set_xlim ([0.0, 5])
    ax1.set_ylim ([0.0, 9])
    ax2.scatter(x, y, label="i=%s" % i)
    ax2.set_xlabel('Y_plot2 title') 
    ax2.set_ylabel('X_plot2 title')
    ax1.legend()
    ax2.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Now my code works fine. My mistake was to left 'plt.show()' at the end of the code.